# IntelliJ IDEA - how to trigger Git conflicts resolving from a command line

Tags: git, intellij-idea, command-line, git-merge-conflict

I use git from mostly from a command line, but for conflicts resolving, I prefer an IDE. Specifically IntelliJ IDEA.

Currently I attempt a rebase, and see conflicts. So I need to go to IDEA and click "VCS -> Git -> resolve conflicts". And then go back to console and run `git rebase --continue`.

I think I can configure `git` to call a program to handle conflicts.

**Is there a way to invoke IDEA's conflicts resolving from a command line?**
Something like `idea --git-resolve-conflicts $(PWD)`.

Perhaps after installing a right plugin? This is what IDEA gives me as help:

```
Usage:
  /usr/local/bin/idea -h | -? | --help
  /usr/local/bin/idea [project_dir]
 /usr/local/bin/idea [-l|--line line] [project_dir|--temp-project] file[:line]
  /usr/local/bin/idea diff <left> <right>
  /usr/local/bin/idea merge <local> <remote> [base] <merged>
```

Answer (score 5):

First thing you have to define the tool to be used for merge resolution in ~/.gitconfig (global) or project/.git/config (just for your project)

```
[mergetool "idea"]
    cmd = /usr/local/bin/idea merge \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = false
[merge]
    tool = idea
```

then in a normal session, when after a `git merge` command some conflict arises, call:

```
git mergetool
```

I edited modifying to false the trustExitCode settings... so that it does not fail when multiple conflicting files.
After each file in the shell is asked confirmation whether the conflict about the current file is solved and then it proceeds with the next one.

Comment: Thanks. this could be what I am looking for.

Comment: is it ok? do you need more indication?

Comment: Seems ok, I have tried it with one conflicting file. I need to try with multiple.

Comment: I modified the answer... it is better to set trustExitCode = false

Answer (score 4):

You could call IDEA as a merge tool - `/usr/local/bin/idea merge <local> <remote> [base] <merged>`. More information at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-intellij-idea-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html

There is no way IDEA could find all conflicts on its own, but you could configure it as the default merge tool for git, as proposed by Carlo. This should work

Comment: I don't understand why wouldn't it find all conflicts? It does just that when you click "Resolve conflicts..." - all conflicts appear and you select them all and click "Merge"... which is basically what I want to invoke.

Comment: It does this based on the parsed output of git and internal workflow. You can just open the repository in the IDE and it will detect all of that, then invoke Resole conflicts action. But there is no way of doing this with a single command line

Comment: Right, @Dmitry, that's what I am looking for. Seems I will have to ask for that feature.